# How to implement protractor grid system using JavaScript?

Tags: protractor

I created web-application using angular-5 for chatting and audio-call. need to implement automation using protractor.
Example test cases: 
1.send message from machine-1 and receive message from machine-2.
2.make call from machine-1 and end call from the machine-2.

How to write protractor test-cases for these kind of scenarios.

As of now my current implementation is like.

```
multiCapabilities: [
         {
            seleniumAddress: 'http://machine1/wd/hub',
            browserName: 'chrome',
            directConnect: true,
            sequential: true,
            specs: [
              'e2e/sender/login.js',
              'e2e/sender/sendmsg.js',
              'e2e/sender/makecall.js']
         }, 
         {
             seleniumAddress: 'http://machine2/wd/hub',
             browserName: 'chrome',
             directConnect: true,
             specs: [
              'e2e/receiver/login.js',
              'e2e/receiver/receivemessage.js',
              'e2e/receiver/endcall.js']
         }
    ]
```

Note: when i run the protractor, both machines will execute the test cases parallel.

How to implement proper test cases using protractor to test these kind of scenarios Please suggest.

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Is it ok if you open browser on same machine on which existing browser is running ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `driver.forkNewDriverInstance()`  https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBrowser.prototype.forkNewDriverInstance to create new browser instance for the same test.